# ¿Como hacer un data annotation personalizado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Necesito validar el rut (dni chileno) que se ingresa en un formulario, para ello estoy utilizando asp.net mvc 5, pero no se como puedo crear mi propio validador para este dato.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar o orientar en como crear este validador?

Comment: La unica orientacion que puedo darte es que crees una expresion regular en tu data annotation te dejo un ejemplo de como seria la validacion con un campo que requiere almenos un numero [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Un numero es requerido")] public int MinAge { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear un validador de anotación de datos personalizado, siga estas líneas de guía:

1. Tu clase tiene que heredar de la clase [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Anula el método [`bool IsValid(object value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679289(v=vs.110).aspx) e implementa la lógica de validación dentro de él.

#### IMPORTANTE Precaución

A veces los desarrolladores comprueban que el valor no es nulo/vacío y devuelve falso. Por lo general, este es un comportamiento incorrecto, porque el validador `Required` se debe verificar, lo que significa que los validadores personalizados solo deben validar datos que no sean nulos, pero devuelvan lo contrario `true` (ver ejemplo). Esto los hará utilizables en campos obligatorios y no obligatorios.

#### Ejemplo (Rango de longitud de cadena)

```
public class StringLengthRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    public StringLengthRangeAttribute()
    {
        this.Minimum = 0;
        this.Maximum = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        {
            int len = strValue.Length;
            return len >= this.Minimum && len <= this.Maximum;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Todas las propiedades se pueden establecer en el atributo que desee configurar.
Algunos ejemplos:

```
[Required]
[StringLengthRange(Minimum = 10, ErrorMessage = "Debe tener> 10 caracteres.")]

[StringLengthRange(Maximum = 20)]

[Required]
[StringLengthRange(Minimum = 10, Maximum = 20)]
```

Cuando una propiedad en particular no está configurada, su valor se establece en el constructor, por lo que siempre tiene un valor. En los ejemplos de uso anteriores, también agregué deliberadamente el validador `Required`, por lo que está en sintonía con la **precaución** anterior que he escrito.

#### Importante

Entonces este validador funcionará en el valor de su modelo que no es necesario, pero cuando está presente lo valida (piense en un campo de texto en un formulario web, eso no es obligatorio, pero si un usuario ingresa un valor, debe ser válido) .

> Para mas información:
>
> - Fuente SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413875/8933039
> - Aquí le dejo este enlace: [Custom Data Annotation Validator Part I : Server Code](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx) que le puede servir...